# How to show multiple result with a user which the user appear once in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Now I am designing a query to get the user name and what they have posted

here is the fields in table "user" and "post"

```
user: user_name, u_id

post: p_id, u_id, content
```

And I want to write a query to display like that

```
user_name        content

Cherry         hi,i am cherry
               hello
Tom            good day today=)
```

But not

```
user_name        content

Cherry         hi,i am cherry
Cherry         hello
Tom            good day today=)
```

How can I achieve that on PHP in table form?

Comment: More like "output" issue, that a "select" issue, if you ask me.

Comment: so keep track of what's been output, and don't output it again if it already has been.

Comment: Can you show us how you are displaying this output?

Comment: Where is the question? use php `if` and variables

Comment: how can I use php if and variabes?? i am a newstarter on php, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` should be helpful to you.  You can read documentation on it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Your query could look like this:

```
select user_name, group_concat(content,"\n") from post group by user_name;
```

This will group all of the posts together by each user, and then concatenate the `content` field of all of a user's rows into a single string separated by newline.

You can see the [SQLFiddle with query and results here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/017641/3)

(Keep in mind that SQLFiddle prints its results, by default, in tabular HTML.  Choose `Run SQL -> Plaintext Output` to see the actual newlines printed out)

**EDITED** (added content below)

If you want to use PHP to handle this, you can do the following:

```
$query = 'select user_name, group_concat(content,"\n") as contents from post group by user_name;'
$result = mysqli_query($query)

print '<table><tr><td>USER NAME</td><td>CONTENTS</td></tr>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  print '<tr>';
  print '<td>' . $result['user_name'] . '</td>';
  print '<td>' . preg_replace("/\n/", '<br>' . $result['contents']) . '</td>';
  print '</tr>';
}
print '</table>';
```

Here are links to documentation on some of the functions I used in this example:

- [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
- [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc)
- [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
    select user.user_name, post.content
    from user inner join post on
        user.u_id = post.u_id
```

get the results, and show them at your convenience. If the user_name comes up more than once, just print it once, and go through all its content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT u . * , (

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( p.content ) 
FROM post p
WHERE p.u_id = u.u_id
) AS combine
FROM user u
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it in a table-like form, you could keep a variable which holds the current username or id.

```
$currentUser = false;

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  echo '<tr><td>';
  if ($row['user_id'] != $currentUser) {
    //print user
    $currentUser = $row['user_id'];
  }
  echo '</td><td>';
  //print content
  echo '</td></tr>';
}
```